# Не отправляются подтверждения регистрации на email django-registration

Tags: python, django

Прикрутил django-registration, настроил setting.py, но почему то попрежнему не отправляет подтверждения на указанное мыло.

Вот код:

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2
AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info.flashcards@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info.flashcards@yandex.ru'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поменяйте это EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
на это: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

Comment: Сделал. Теперь выдает:

SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/register/
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.5.5
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
Exception Value: 
(535, 'Incorrect authentication data')
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py in login, line 614
Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5

Comment: Вы указали неверный логин и (или) пароль для авторизации на SMTP-сервере

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас указан backend для вывода писем в консоль, реальной отправки он не делает.